# jquery append add/remove tr doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, append

I don't know what would be the problem of my code. i test it in http://jsfiddle.net/jc_garcia0527/XwcK6/ and it is working fine.

But using it in the browser. it didn't work.

i am using jquery 1.9.1

Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".add_row").click(function(){
    $("#dynamic").append('<tr><td><table align="center"><tbody><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="0" class="id" id="checkbox" checked><b>Supplier:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="supp[]"></td></tr><tr><td><b>Material:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="mat[]"></td></tr><tr><td><b>P.O No:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="supp[]"></td></tr><tr><td><b>DR/SI No.:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="supp[]"></td></tr><tr><td align="center" colspan="2">ETC.....</td></tr></tbody></table></td><td align="center"><button class="remove_row">X</button></td></tr>');
});
$("#dynamic").on('click','.remove_row',function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
});
```

And Here's where i apply it.

```
<table align='center' border='1'>
<thead>
    <th style="padding:10px;">Sample Add rows</th>
    <th width='10'><button class='add_row'>+</button></th>
</thead>
<tbody id='dynamic'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table align='center'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="0" class="id" id='checkbox' checked>
                            <b>Supplier:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type='text' name='supp[]'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Material:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type='text' name='mat[]'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>P.O No:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type='text' name='supp[]'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>DR/SI No.:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type='text' name='supp[]'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align='center' colspan='2'>
                            ETC.....
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td align='center'>
            <button class='remove_row'>X</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
   </table>
```

i also check my firebug and there is no breakpoints. when i click the add button the appended TR will appear and disappear again.

### UPDATE

```
<form action='' method='POST' name='test'>
<table align='center' border='1'>
<thead>
    <th style="padding:10px;">Sample Add rows</th>
    <th width='10'><button class='add_row'>+</button></th>
</thead>
<tbody id='dynamic'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table align='center'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="0" class="id" id='checkbox' checked>
                            <b>Supplier:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type='text' name='supp[]'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Material:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type='text' name='mat[]'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>P.O No:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type='text' name='supp[]'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>DR/SI No.:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type='text' name='supp[]'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align='center' colspan='2'>
                            ETC.....
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td align='center'>
            <button class='remove_row'>X</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
  </table>
  <center><input type='submit' value='SAVE'></center>
  </form>
```

This would be the format. when there's a form the jquery is not working.

Answer (score 0):

i add preventDefault();

code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".add_row").click(function(){
    $("#dynamic").append('<tr><td><table align="center"><tbody><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="0" class="id" id="checkbox" checked><b>Supplier:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="supp[]"></td></tr><tr><td><b>Material:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="mat[]"></td></tr><tr><td><b>P.O No:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="supp[]"></td></tr><tr><td><b>DR/SI No.:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="supp[]"></td></tr><tr><td align="center" colspan="2">ETC.....</td></tr></tbody></table></td><td align="center"><button class="remove_row">X</button></td></tr>');
});
```

To:

```
$(".add_row").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#dynamic").append('<tr><td><table align="center"><tbody><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="0" class="id" id="checkbox" checked><b>Supplier:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="supp[]"></td></tr><tr><td><b>Material:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="mat[]"></td></tr><tr><td><b>P.O No:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="supp[]"></td></tr><tr><td><b>DR/SI No.:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="supp[]"></td></tr><tr><td align="center" colspan="2">ETC.....</td></tr></tbody></table></td><td align="center"><button class="remove_row">X</button></td></tr>');
    });
```